# Как поменять иконки к файловым расширениям в Linux?

Tags: linux, mime

Нет желания устанавливать [Assogiate](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/assogiate), хочу ручками.

### Первый вариант :

В папке */usr/share/mime/packages* находится файл *freedesktop.org.xml* - в нем находятся основные настройки по отображению иконок для различных типов файлов. После редактирования нужно не забыть обновить базы командой :

```
sudo update-mime-database -V /usr/share/mime
```

Этот xml большой и не понятно куда вставлять путь к png или svg файлу.

### Второй вариант:

Нахожу такое с этого [источника](https://unixforum.org/index.php?showtopic=74026):

> И так, сначала определимся для какого типа файлов мы будем менять "картинку"...
>   (в моем примере это *.lpi - файл проекта на Lazarus).
>   Первым делом в любом текстовом редакторе набираем (и сохраняем как user-lpi.xml) :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mime-info xmlns="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info">
<mime-type type="user/lpi">
<comment>Lazarus Project File</comment>
<glob pattern="*.lpi"/>
</mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

> Это скрипт который служит для определения нового MIME типа в системе!
>   Далее открываем терминал и пишем:

```
xdg-mime install user-lpi.xml
```

> Почти все.. Осталось самое главное - определиться с иконкой!
>   Выбираем понравившуюся картинку (можно 128x128, 64х64, 32x32 ...) в формате PNG (или SVG), переименовываем ее в user-lpi.png и копируем в папку:

```
/usr/share/icons/Human/scalable/mimetypes
```

**Вопросы** :
1. Как правильно отредактировать freedesktop.org.xml, что в первом варианте ? (для последующего обновления)
2. Куда сохранять подобный user-lpi.xml из второго варианта ?

Answer (score 2):

1) Второй вариант по моему и есть правильный вариант обновления freedesktop.org.xml

2) Положи файл user-lpi.xml в `/usr/share/mime/packages` чтоб применить на всю систему. А иконки лучше хранить в папке `~/.local/share/icons/hicolor`(так делает wine) или `/usr/local/share/icons/hicolor`. Иконки из **hicolor** применяются ко всем темам, которые не имеют своей иконки с таким же именем - не надо мучать темы.